# when i am clicking on login button without input it starts another activity?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-sharedpreferences

I am using shared preference and if else condition but when i am clicking on login button without touching text box  it starts another activity and after giving input in text box its working fine why?

```
login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userinfo",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            final String name =sharedPref.getString("username","");
            if(userLogInText.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registration ID is not Matching",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }



        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your default `SharedPreferences` value is blank and your `EditText` value is also blank that's why your if condition is going true.

Check your EditText value is empty or not.

Try below code.

```
if(userLogInText.getText().toString().trim().length()>0 && userLogInText.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
 }
else {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registration ID is not Matching",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```